# Upload Gigabytes of files to Storage Account from Django

Tags: reactjs, django, scalability, azure-file-share

I have a project setup with `Django` and `ReactJs`. The use case is, users will upload Gigabytes of files and those are to be stored to their respective folders in Azure Storage Account File Shares service (using Azure Python SDK).

1. How do I upload them through backend (Django)?
2. How can it be handled in the scalability perspective as well?

I came across RabbitMQ and Kafka to redirect the upload through backend, but since it is not yet implemented. I'm looking for suggestions and other possible ways to do the same.

Any suggestions to the scenario would be helpful.
Thank you!